# Make file manager mounts of smb shares permanent

Tags: networking, mount, kubuntu, samba, fstab

Is there a sequence of steps in kubuntu GUI to make mounted smb shares from other PC on same home network permanent?

Yes, I can edit fstab.

But that's not the question. In MSFT OS in file explorer I can search and 'map network drive' a shared drive from other PC. Then there is a check box to make the 'map' permanent by re-establishing it at boot. So my assumption is that the MSFT equivalent of the fstab file (as shame that it's not user accessible) is being modified by file explorer.

Can the same be done in kubuntu with one of the provided file managers? konqueror and dolphin come to mind.

And BTW, yes the dolphin can access a smb share via it's GUI. But once I saw the share in the dolphin UI I did a 'mount' command and would not see an entry that looked familiar referring to the device. Also no change in fstab.

How does kubuntu handle that?

Cheers,
Gert

Answer (score 0):

File managers nowadays use `gio mount` (it replaced almost all other methods like `gvfs-mount`, `smbclient`). Mind that file managers can mount without the need to ask for user and password if those can be provided by the system. It can also accept user and password from Kerberos. Gnome-keyring, a `.servercreds` file.

```
gio mount <protocol>://<servername>/<sharename>
```

User and password are not provided with the command as this would be visible.

From command line the same rules apply: user and password need to be provided, and the normal method is to add a line to `/etc/fstab`.

> But once I saw the share in the dolphin UI I did a 'mount' command and would not see an entry that looked familiar referring to the device. Also no change in fstab.

`gio` mounted devices are listed by doing:

```
gio mount -l
```

> (as shame that it's not user accessible)

Any other method would lessen the security of a system.